# Unable to assign autowired child bean to parent object in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**XML Config:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


    <bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say_Impl" id="id_Say_Impl" />
</beans>
```

**Say_I**

```
public interface Say_I
    {
        public void Say_I_m1();
    }
```

**Say_Impl**

```
public class Say_Impl implements Say_I
    {
        public void Say_I_m1()
            {
                System.out.println("inside : public void Say_I_m1() \n");
            }
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
public class Controller_Test implements SpringApplicationContextInterface
    {
        @Autowired
        private Say_Impl say_Impl;

        //Below line not assigning, need to reassign into method
        private Say_I say_I =  (Say_I) say_Impl;
//        private Say_I say_I =  (Say_I) applicationContext.getBean("id_Say_Impl");

        @RequestMapping(value = "/test10")
        public String Test1()
        {
            say_I = say_Impl;
            System.out.println("Say_Impl_auto : "+say_Impl);
            System.out.println("Say_I : "+say_I);
            say_I.Say_I_m1();
            return " request value = test10 ";
        }  
    }

public interface SpringApplicationContextInterface 
{
 ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanConfig.xml");
}


@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:beanConfig.xml")
public class Courses  extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) 
    {
        return application.sources(Courses.class);
    }

}
```

The above code is part of a spring boot application.

This line of code inside "Controller_Test" class :

```
 private Say_I say_I =  (Say_I) say_Impl;
```

is not assigning Say_Impl object "say_Impl" reference into its parent  object say_I. But if i am assigning it again into  Test1() method then it is working.

But the below line of code is assigning the say_Impl reference into say_I object.

```
private Say_I say_I =  (Say_I) applicationContext.getBean("id_Say_Impl");
```

Now my question is, when i am taking the say_impl object by autowiring why i need to reassign it into method? Is there any way to make it working without reassigning?

When i am taking the bean by application context then i need not to reassign, Why?

Comment: You should be auto wiring a field of type `Say_I` and not `Say_Impl`. Basically you should never inject a concrete type when you are using interfaces. Also to give a better answer there is too many missing pieces in your question and things that are unclear.

Comment: @M. Deinum, what kind of info u need more?

Comment: Your xml config is missing parts, how is this all loaded, what is the `SpringApplicationContextInterface` that your controller implements etc. Nonetheless you still should be aftowring a `Say_I` and not a `Say_Impl` in your code when programming to interfaces.

Comment: @M. Deinum, hope now it is clear.

Comment: Please tell that isn't code you are actually planning on using! Please drop the `SpringApplicationContextInterface` as fast as you can... Never create a new application context just because you need one. Delete that interface...  And as stated numerous times before you should be auto wiring your `Say_I` field and remove your `Say_Impl` field.

Comment: @M. Deinum, no i am not going to use SpringApplicationContextInterface, used to test purpose. actually i am not understanding ur statement "you still should be aftowring a Say_I and not a Say_Impl in your code when programming to interfaces". So what should i do instead of Say_Impl field? How can i assign? would u clarify a bit more?

Comment: As stated before use `Say_I` NOT `Say_Impl` (not sure what is so hard about that?).

Comment: Why do you want to use `xml` in Spring Boot application?

Comment: @M. Deinum  ok i got it. just used "Autowired private Say_I say_I" and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very ugly code, legacy xml with spring boot WTF?

Try this

```
@Autowired
private Say_I say_I;
```

or better:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Courses {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Courses.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public class Controller_Test {

        @Autowired
        private Say_I say_I;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/test10")
        public String Test1() {
            System.out.println("Say_I : " + say_I);
            say_I.Say_I_m1();
            return " request value = test10 ";
        }
    }   

    @Component
    public class Say_I {    
        void Say_I_m1() {
            System.out.println("inside : public void Say_I_m1() \n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem with XML?

Comment: xml is not compilable :) take a look at example above, all code is compilable and error prone/ type safe.

Comment: actually i do feel more comfortable with XML.:)

Comment: it is better (easier) to start with spring from java without xml :) Whole your xml file can be replaced with one line `@Component`. So, I dont see any reason to use xml :)

Comment: You can unit test Java based configuration classes.